# Access vuex store in before Vue instance is initialized

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to check if the user is validated before entering routes. I'm using vue-router's beforeEach to tackle this. But I realize that I can check the vuex store before the vue instance is initialized.

Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import store from '../store/store.js';
import App from '../app.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import progressBar from '../plugins/progress-bar';
import { routes } from '../router-config';
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync';

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(VeeValidate)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(Vuex)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'hash',
    saveScrollPosition: true,
  });

  sync(store, router)

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    debugger;
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next({ path: '/' })
    } else if (to.path === "/") {
      next({ path: '/dashboard'})
    } else {
      next()
    }
  });

  const app = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    router,
    store,
    axios,
    render: h => h(App),
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {
      App,
    }
  });
})
```

How can I access `this` so that I can do something like this `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn`? Am I thinking of this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `this.$store`. You have `store`. Just use `store`.

```
store.getters.isLoggedIn
```

`this.$store` is just a reference to `store` that you can use inside Vue components. But anywhere you import the store you have access to everything you need.

Comment: Hmm. If I try `store` I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined`.

Comment: @bitwise You have to be importing store somewhere or creating the Vue wouldn't work.

Comment: Yea, I'm definitely importing the store. Not sure why it's not defined

Comment: @Bitwise where exactly are you trying to use the store? Can you show in the code in your question?

Comment: Yea, I updated so that it shows the entire main.js file. I'm trying to call store within the beforeEach router function

Comment: @Bitwise I'm unable to replicate your issue. Here is an example that just logs out the store in beforeEach. https://codesandbox.io/s/73y0zo3mj1